# Get source code of web.whatsapp.com

Tags: php, whatsapp

Is it possible to get the source code of web.whatsapp.com?

```
$ch = curl_init("https://web.whatsapp.com/");
$fp = fopen("example_homepage.txt", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

It doesn't work. I also tried file_get_contents().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible, as long as WhatsApp Corp doesn't open source it.